# Change laravel directory structure

Tags: php, laravel, directory-structure

atm i'm beginning to develop a big application and the current structure of laravel just doesn't fit what i had in thought. The controllers, models and views are all in seperate folders just bunched up and things could get messy when there's loads of them.

So I was hoping I could change the default way laravel loads it's controllers views and models. My approach would be something like this:

```
-App
--Content
---Login
----Controller
----Model
----View
----Js
---Home
----Controller
----Model
----View
----Js
--BaseContent
---BaseLayout
---BaseController
---BaseJS
```

So when the route is home the controller model view and javascript all get bundled in a folder instead of having all of it in one controller directory, model directory, view directory etc.

So my question is does someone know how I could change the way laravel load's it's dependency's? I'm kinda hoping for a configuration file I just can't seem to find.

Comment: The structure you want isn't so good as you think it is. Laravel's structure is good and avoids unnecessary routings to other folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your thoughts. You want to group by feature.

It's possible. All you need are namespaces conform PSR-4. In `composer.json` you can link/specify the namespaces and paths, for example, you have in your controller this line:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

In `composer.json` see the following fragment in `autoload`:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
}
```

The namespace `App` refers to the directory `app`, and all classes with the namespace beginning with `App\` will be autoloaded. So it's simple for your to change the directory structure.