# Laravel: Can I change folder structure

Tags: php, laravel

Standard Laravel structure is

```
app
---http
------Controllers
---------MyComponentController
---Models
------MyComponentModel
---database
------MyComponentnMigration
```

I wonder if there is the chance to change the folder structure to:

```
app
---MyComponent // kind of a package that holds all mandatory elements 
------Controllers
---------Controller
------Models
---------Model
------database
---------Migration
```

as it would make much more sense.

**update**

**why does people vote it down ? it is a serious question, a model has a dependency to a migration. so if you want to use the model in another project you have to search the migration in the project and all other relevant items that has a connection with it. if all mandatory files would be structured under one parent node it would be just a copy and paste.

It would be at least honest to understand why those down voters think this isn't a good idea
 **

Comment: Yes, you may do so.

Comment: cool, any ideas how it could work ?  I assume some loaders have to be changed for it

Comment: Update every namespace referencing `App\Http\Controllers`, `App\Models`, etc. to your desired structure.

Comment: I feel that won't work . e.g  routes don't have a namespace, how would it target the correct controller ?

Comment: Adding to the structure is probably better than trying to reinvent it. I.e. having an `app\Http\Controllers` parallel to `app\MyComponent\Http\Controllers` would be a logical approach if you want Controllers for an individual component. That being said, it could also live in `app\Http\Controllers\MyComponent`, so there's many ways to approach this.

Comment: It's entirely possible, with a bit of work. Here's a Laravel 4 answer that'll get you mostly there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132220/laravel-4-package-or-modules/18137352#18137352

Comment: In short, yes. But, it requires some work. Check this answer too -
 I'm not sure what version of Laravel this is, though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011096/change-laravel-directory-structure

Comment: And this - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-i-can-change-laravel-directory-structure

Comment: And also review this - https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/structure

Comment: And this - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/structure#the-root-app-directory

Comment: The above links will help you understand the implications and what to consider when changing the directory structure.

Comment: cool thanks. those links are helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, actually we already did what you're thinking. We create a separate Folder and inside of it `Models, Controllers, Requests , Views, Routes` You just need to update the `RouteProviders` to rellocate your Controllers by modifying the namespace and for the `Views`. you just need to update via `config folder` .